# How to add validation error on input fields jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I put a validation error on the input field itself? because I have now showing only the error in the div id="result". I just want to know how to put it on the input box.

And I'm just new using on jQuery Ajax code, Is my code correct in jquery ajax syntax?

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-group" method="post" action="actions/forgot_password_action.php">
<div id="result"></div>
<table class="table-condensed" style="text-align:right">
    <tr>
        <td>Username:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" size="40"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>New Password:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password" id="password" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Password must be atleast 8 characters"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="repassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="repassword" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Please re-enter password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Answer for security purposes<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="iqama" placeholder="What is your Iqama No.?" id="security" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><a href="index.php">Log in</a> <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
    <tr>
</table>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("button#submit").click(function(){

  $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
    $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
    function(data) {
        $("div#result").html(data);
    });

$("#myForm").submit(function(){
     return false;
});
```

});

PHP

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
$iqama = $_POST['iqama'];

$check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
$get_lastname = mysqli_fetch_array($check);

$dbiqama = $get_lastname['iqama'];
$dbusername = $get_lastname['username'];

if(!empty($username) and !empty($password) and !empty($repassword) and !empty($iqama)){

    if($dbiqama == $iqama and $dbusername == $username){
        if($password == $repassword){

            if(strlen($password) > 7){
                $encrypt = sha1($password);
                mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET password = '".$encrypt."' WHERE username = '".$username."'");
                echo "<script>alert('Try to Sign in now.!'); window.location.href='index.php';</script>";   
            }else{
                echo "<div class=panel-danger>";
                    echo "<div class=panel-heading>Password must be atleast 8 characters!</div>";       
                echo "</div>";  
            }   
        }else{
            echo "<div class=panel-danger>";
                echo "<div class=panel-heading>Password does not match!</div>";     
            echo "</div>";  
        }
    }else{
        echo "<div class=panel-danger>";
            echo "<div class=panel-heading>Invalid username or Iqama No.</div>";        
        echo "</div>";  
    }

}else{
    echo "<div class=panel-danger>";
        echo "<div class=panel-heading>Fill up all fields!</div>";      
    echo "</div>";  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [HTML5 forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML)?  This would help some of your validations.  To place the response in the input, you need to change this: `$("div#result").html(data);` to target the input elements.

Comment: I didnt try it.  Can you help me please? What will i replace for this   $("div#result").html(data); ?

Comment: You need a cohesive strategy here, imho.  Give up on the echoing out all those danger panels, just stick one in your dom and return all the error messages there.  Validate the pwd match on the client side.

Comment: So Sir @jmargolisvt I Dont have an Idea of how to do that, Because im just new using jquery